# Is it correct to use to_date() in hibernate if date is stored as string like (132011) in Database?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a table "Products(id, name, productionDate)" in Oracle database. "date" column is defined as String and it has value like "131120" (1st two digits for year, 2nd two digits for year & final two digits for date). I need a sorted output based on date using Hibernate. SQL query to do this is like the following:

```
select * from products order by to_date(productionDate, 'YYMMDD') desc;
```

This sql query is fine when I try from command prompt.

But when I tried to use this query using Hibernate, I am unable to retrieve the information and i got some error. My Hibernate code is like the following:

```
.......

String queryString = "from products p order by to_date(p.productionDate, 'YYMMDD')  desc";
Query query = s.createQuery(queryString);

.....
```

And I got the error like (Only some lines are given below which is helpful to understand)

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query
......
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

Bean Definition is like the following:

```
......

String id;
String name;
String productionDate;

// getter and setter
```

Doesn't HQL support to_date()? If not, what is the way to find this type of query output?

Comment: You forgot the single quotes around YYMMDD. Why don't you do the right thing and store the date as a date?

Comment: I put single quotes around YYMMDD but still i am getting the errors.

Comment: Can you try to execute it as a native query?  See examples - http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql-queries-examples/

Comment: Thats propably because you have data on it that is not on the format that you are putting. If your database is oracle you can do this: `select * from products where not regexp_like(productionDate, '0-9{6}')`

Answer (score 1):

HQL does not support to_date - at least according to docs [HQL expressions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions). If all of the dates are greater than Jan 1, 2000, you can sort by the raw string value instead of converting.

You can use a native sql query using to_date. Look at the log output at org.hibernate.SQL to make sure that hibernate is not making too many unnecessary queries on joined entities.