# Independently comparing date in HQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, fluent-nhibernate, hql

I have this Hibernate query.

```
select  e  from Article e where (e.PublishDate <= '04/02/2014')
```

the query resulting no rows, because with current system format the right query is (month at first):

```
select  e  from Article e where (e.PublishDate <= '02/04/2014')
```

How do I compare the date so it could compared independently (doesn't depend on system date format)

Comment: I would try: select e from Article e where (e.PublishDate <= to_date('04/02/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))

Comment: What if `e.PublishDate` format reversed to  `'DD/MM/YYYY'` ?

Comment: @DNac I think hibernate don't have `to_date` function. Right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105366/is-it-correct-to-use-to-date-in-hibernate-if-date-is-stored-as-string-like-13

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you use the ISO format for date.  Typically the ISO format works when other formats don't work.  ISO is YYYY-MM-DD  or just YYYYMMDD if you don't you separators.  some databases will allow you to use YYYY/MM/DD but when using MSSQL as my backing store I use the ISO format with dashes.  Another format that works well with SQL server is YYYY-MMM-DD which translates to 2014-APR-02 for today.  You can find the 3 letter ISO values for each month online and if your using .NET then you can use:

```
string.format("{0:YYYY-MMM-DD}",dateValue)
```

This will allow you to use the internal vb.net datetime objects and format them to values required by your select statement when you need to.

I have found that whatever the system date format is set to the database engine itself will allow you to compare to an ISO standard value.  While I do not know what happens in nHibernate specifically, this trick has worked for me with every single other O/R mapper I have ever used so it should work here as well.